# The equivalence of 1-consistency and Σ_1 soundness in Σ_1 complete theory

Tags: logic, arithmetic, foundations

Let $T$ be $\Sigma_1$ complete theory. I could understand the proof that 1-consistency of $T$ implies $\Sigma_1$ soundness of $T$, but I couldn't vice versa.

I wonder if there are some missing hypotheses about $T$ because the book now I'm referencing is a casual/informal/not strict book.

Comment: I learned that $1$-consistency is just another name for $\Sigma_1$-soundness (that's e.g. the usage on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory)) - what's your definition of $1$-consistency?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think it's like $\omega$-consistent, but just for $\varphi$ being $\Delta_0$.

Comment: 1-consistency is $\omega$-consistency just for $\Delta_1$ formula.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $T$ is $\Sigma_1$ sound and that  $T\vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$, where $\varphi$ is $\Delta_0$. Since $T$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound, $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is true, and thus $\varphi(m)$ is true for some $m\in\mathbb N.$ Then by $\Sigma_1$-completeness, $T\vdash \varphi(\bf m).$ So $T$ is 1-consistent.

Comment: Why is $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @minerva Do you mean why is $m\in\mathbb N$? That's what it means for $\exists x\varphi(x)$ to be true, that there is an $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\varphi(m)$ holds over $\mathbb N.$

Comment: $T \vdash \exists x \varphi (x)$ means any model of $T$ has $x$ such that satisfies $\varphi (x)$. My question is $x$ possibly out of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @minerva That's true, but I don't see your point. That's what it means for $T\vdash \exists x\varphi(x),$ but it's not what it means for $\exists x\varphi (x)$ to be true (i.e. true in $\mathbb N$, which is what 'sound' is relative to).

Comment: There are only two hypotheses ($\Sigma_1$ completeness and $\Sigma_1$ soundness) that $T$ should meet, so I think I cannot say that $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $T$.

Comment: I doubt that the book forgot showing $T$ should meet an additional hypothesis such as $T \supset PA$.

Comment: @minerva You can't say $\mathbb N$ satisfies $T.$ But you can say that if $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_1$ and $T\vdash \varphi$ then $\mathbb N\models \varphi.$ That's what $\Sigma_1$-soundness means. And $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is $\Sigma_1.$